# Stream Binary Data over WebSockets using Ratchet for PHP

Tags: php, stream, websocket, binary-data, ratchet

I've successfully setup a WebSocket server using Ratchet for PHP on Windows/IIS. I went with Ratchet's available WAMP(WebSocket Application Messaging Protocol) setup so that I have Pub/Sub and RPC capabilities. That's been great for minor things like chatting or simple updates. What I am curious about is how to stream raw binary data (like audio/video) to a target audience (1 or more people)...

**Server(s) :** 
- Windows 7 (64-bit) / Windows 2008 Server Enterprise (64-bit) 
- PHP 5.4.x 
- Ratchet (WebSocket Server) http://socketo.me/docs/wamp 
 
**Client Setup:** 
- Autobahn|JS http://autobahn.ws/js/ 
- when.js https://github.com/cujojs/when

Is there a solution out there using my setup that allows me to stream binary data to a target audience? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can setup the streaming like this: [Send and receive binary data over web sockets in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766802/send-and-receive-binary-data-over-web-sockets-in-javascript)

And then the playback of the audio: [Streaming Binary with Node.js and WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638096/streaming-binary-with-node-js-and-websockets)

Haven't found anything useful for video playback via streamed data and i think currently it's either unavailable or highly experimental.

Comment: More examples: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/webrtc-integration.html

Comment: These suggestions are appreciated but I've looked into them and they're all node.js implementations. Not PHP(using Ratchet). I will fiddle around a bit and see if I can make something work.

Comment: @DigitalTrifecta Did you bump into something worthy eventually?

Comment: @Azuli42 - To save myself a rather large headache I eventually switched to Node / Express / Socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

[Somebody](https://github.com/dizard) has a fork for Ratchet and he claims implementing binary data send/receive.

Take a look at [this link](https://github.com/dizard/Ratchet).

And please don't forget to mark this answer as your accepted solution.
Good luck

Comment: I found https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/393#issuecomment-329532173 but still haven't figured it out.