# play audio file and make the user not able to know the file name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-audio

what i want is very much not a specific code , so what i want is to play a audio file on some page and this audio file in directory, the page has to call the audio from the directory by the file name and play it on the page, so i want to play the audio and when some one inspect the page he will not be able to see the file name, how i can do it ? i tried

```
<html><p>just a word</p></html>
```

I Tried

```
just another code
```

Comment: What do the things you have tried have to do with playing an audio file?

Comment: Stream it from server? If it's client side it can't be traced back to the source by reading the code.

Comment: Audio can be played using javascript. Javascript code can be removed visually, but people will still be able to see the network request

Comment: @Cheese how can i do that ? streaming from server

Comment: @Thakkie its just for making stack over flow accept my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440262/web-audio-api-for-live-streaming

Comment: you tried what?